# reactjs retain field props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to retain component props after emitting back event. 
Desc: i have a container it has multiple components (in a same view) in one of component has two fields and one button "continue". After entering some values into those fields ,  clicking on continue button its going to another component in this component we have two fields and two buttons one is back and continue when i click on back button its going to previous component but not retaining the props which entered on those . can you help me how to retain data.

Comment: Please show us some code which you tried so far.

Comment: Thats a very hard "question" to read.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for you is to have a parent component which holds all the data in its state. Parent container component passes the data to the children components you have as props, also it passes the callbacks to so a child can update the data. Given that you parent is always rendered and thus is never unmounted the data will be always there.

Something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { name: 'John' }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <Child name={this.state.name} onNameChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value})} />
    </div>
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>The name "{this.props.name}" is saved in the Parent</p>
      <input type="text" value={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onNameChange} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

A more complicated solution is to use something like Flux or Redux, but I believe it will be a bit too much for you now.